# cant start nancy self host without admin rights

Tags: c#, nancy

My app uses Nancy Selfhosting. When I launch it without admin rights I get a System.Net.HttpListenerException "Access Denied".

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        var nancyHost = new Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:80/"));
        nancyHost.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }
```

I have also tried different ports without success. Strangely, I dont get any Exceptions when launching a HttpListener that listens to the same Url.  What could be causing this exception?

Comment: Is something running on port 80 already?

Comment: I think your `HttpListener` test is flawed.  I get Access Denied during `.GetContext()` when I'm not elevated on windows 7.

Comment: Well of course theres some more application logic in my Programm. And the whole Application works perfectly with a "self - build" Webserver built around the HttpListener. I just wanted to use nancy because of expandability etc. But having to start it with admin rights could be a nogo for our customer.

Answer (score 47):

You need to set the self-host configuration to not rewrite the localhost route via the [`RewriteLocalhost` property](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy).

```
namespace NancyApplication1
{
    using System;
    using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:3579");
            var config = new HostConfiguration();

            // (Change the default RewriteLocalhost value)
            config.RewriteLocalhost = false;

            using (var host = new NancyHost(config, uri))
            {
                host.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Your application is running on " + uri);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any [Enter] to close the host.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this out by trying and failing a bit, but [this page explains the reason behind.](http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2013/05/29/using-iis-express-in-vs-welcome-page)

Comment: But it only allows me to access the address from `localhost` instead of the ip of the machine, or the client will see 400 error. Do you have idea how to fix that?

Comment: @JeffreyZhao Have a look at Ashtonian's answer.

Comment: @robpnv changing ACL requires admin privilege.

Comment: Helped resolve issues between Win 7 and Win 10 installs.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively - From the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin):

> Note that on Windows hosts a HttpListenerException may be thrown with an Access Denied message. To resolve this the URL has to be added to the ACL. 
>   Also but the port may need to be opened on the machine or corporate firewall to allow access to the service.

Add to ACL by running the following command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=DOMAIN\username
```

if you need to remove from ACL:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hosting Nancy with Kestrel. It's really simple:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var owinHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://+:12345/")
        .Build();

    owinHost.Run();
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
    }
}
```

The only difficulty is to prepare all the dlls (30+) required. We should definitely use NuGet to resolve all the dependencies.